# Laravel 6 Database Notification not working in production

Tags: laravel

I have database notification which is working fine in local. It sends emails as well as database notification. But When I uploaded it in PRODUCTION, the email(toEmail) is sending email fine, but the database notification(toDatabase) is not working. I'm used laraval forge to deploy the application. I don't think is the problem with queue work because Emails are working fine.

```
class DBMailNewPaymentAddedgNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
  {
     use Queueable;

public $payment;


public function __construct($payment)
{
    $this->payment = $payment;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return explode(',' ,$notifiable->notification_preference);
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Nouvelle action sur le système.')
                ->line('Vous recevez cet e-mail car il y a une nouvelle notification dans le système')
                ->action('Veuillez vous connecter', url('/login'));
}


public function toDatabase()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'Nouveau paiement soumis',
        'category' => 'finance',
        'type' => 'added',
        'icon' => 'cash',
        'note_title' => 'Paiement '.$this->payment->ref_number.' soumis ',
        'note_desc' => 'par l\'utilisateur '.$this->payment->updatedBy->nom.' '.$this->payment->updatedBy->nom,
        'added_by_user_id' => $this->payment->updatedBy->id,
        'item_id' => $this->payment->id
    ];
}
```

> `.env QUEUE_CONNECTION=database // Is set to database in local as well as in production`
>
> And This is how I call the notification class in controller
>   `$users = User::wherePermissionIs('journaux-actions-paiement')->get();
>             $when = now()->addMinutes(2);
>             $users->each->notify((new DBMailNewPaymentAddedgNotification($payment))->delay($when));`

Comment: Have you started your queue worker?

Comment: Yes, the email on the same notification class is working. It's only the database notification on the same class is not working. I tried without queuing and didn't work.

Comment: Then what is $notifiable->notification_preference in the db? sure a space has not snuck in or similar?

Comment: @mrhn I'm feeling little bit embarrassed, but that might sounds like it. I will keep you posted if that was issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wrote up an answer, so we can go through the "official" channels and not do it all in the comment sections :) something a critical are you sure about? is enough to find the bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, as it works in local i would assume either you have not started your worker.

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Other than that, it can only be `$notifiable->notification_preference` that does not hold the correct values.

Comment: you are correct. I added manually the database notification_preference  in local, but I forget to set it up for each user in production. That was good catch from your end. Thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 1):

you should add database in your via function

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}
```